# I can host .net core 5 web application on IIS but not web api

Tags: .net-core, iis-7, asp.net-core-webapi

I get 404 error when I host .Net Core 5 **Web API** on IIS.
I can host Web Application with no issues, though.
Any idea why?

Comment: When you see 404 errors, what are the URLs? Check your routing rules, and make sure those URLs are valid and being routed to the correct actions.

Comment: Is there any URL of error message? You may refer to this post https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-fix-404-error-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Comment: Please check if your WebAPI is hosted as a sub application and if you are using correct URL based on the route you configured for that endpoint(s). Besides, please check and compare the actual HTTP(S) and port you configure for your site/application with your request URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for answering/commenting on my question.
I realized that I was using wrong url for testing my api endpoints. So, hosted the web api as a website in IIS, and it worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of web application runs successfully? Make sure all of the required modules is installed. IIS 7 is pretty old version, make sure all of the required steps are performed.

[Microsoft's guide on hosting on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)